# How to filter users in the queryset by the group to which they belong to?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-queryset

I have a `queryset` with the users:

```
<QuerySet [<User: usr0>, <User: usr1>]>
```

I know that I can verify if the user belongs to the group like so:

```
In [18]: usr1 = queryset[1]                                                                                                                                                                                        

In [19]: usr1.groups.filter(name='Partners').exists()                                                                                                                                                              
Out[19]: True
```

How can I filter out all the users from the `queryset` which do not belong to the custom group(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the queryset, with:

```
queryset.filter(groups__name='Partners')
```

Here we construct a queryset that will only contain `User`s that belong to a group with the name `'Partners'`.